# How to create multiple arrays of random numbers in js?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a matrix of 3 arrays with 10 elements in each array.  Each element should be a random number between 1 and 10.  I wanted to use a single function to generate each of the arrays, and used this:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
var array3 = [];

var tempName;

function fcnArrayGenerate(){
    let i = 1;
    while (i < 4){
        tempName = "array" + i;
        let j = 0;
        while (j < 10){
            tempName.push((Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1));
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    console.log(array1);
    console.log(array2);
    console.log(array3);
}
```

However, when I run the function, I receive an error stating that "tempName.push is not a function."  Any assistance on how to correct this would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: `"array" + i` will not reference the array1 variable, but it will be a string "array1". tempName will be a string and string does not have `push` method, hence the error.
You can create a multidimensional array in javascript. `var array = [[1,8], [2,9], [3,5]]`. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using three variables for three different arrays, you can use a single [multidimensional array](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/multidimensional-array) to store those three arrays.

```
let array = [[], [], []];

function fcnArrayGenerate() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i <= 2) {
    let j = 0;
    while (j < 10) {
      array[i].push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
// call the function
fcnArrayGenerate();
// now print the arrays as tables
console.table(array);
console.table(array[0]);
console.table(array[1]);
console.table(array[2]);
```

Note: `console.table()` allows you to print out arrays and objects to the console in tabular form.

Comment: This was an elegant solution and exactly what I was looking for.  The initial array declaration will be a bit tedious in that my full scale run will require a matrix of 68x38, but at least I was able to scale it down from 170x95.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to push into `tempName` you have to initialise it with an empty array first. Right now it’s undefined. Hence you’re seeing the error as you can’t push something to `undefined`

Do this:
`var tempName = []`

Answer (score 0):

To make variable names `incremental`, you can pass them as `objects`.

```js
var data = {
  array1: [],
  array2: [],
  array3: []
}

function fcnArrayGenerate(){
    let i = 1;
    while (i < 4){
        let j = 0;
        while (j < 10){
            data['array' + i].push((Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1));
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    console.log(data.array1);
    console.log(data.array2);
    console.log(data.array3);
}

fcnArrayGenerate();
```